# Why parsing date in clojure shifts the result 2 hours back

Tags: date, clojure, formatter

Clojure code

```
(def fmt (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "yyyy-MM-dd"))
#'user/fmt
user=> (.parse fmt "2015-07-10")
#inst "2015-07-09T22:00:00.000-00:00"
```

Analogous Java code:

```
public class DateFmt {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        final Date date = sdf.parse("2015-07-10");

        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

While Java code prints: Fri Jul 10 00:00:00 CEST 2015 (which is what I expect), but Clojure shifts 2 hours back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a difference between Clojure's [`instant`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.instant-api.html) and Java's `Date`, the big piece being that the time offset is optional.

> Unlike RFC3339:
>
> - we only parse the timestamp format
> - timestamp can elide trailing components
> - time-offset is optional (defaults to +00:00)

So, Clojure's time is always tied to UTC, whereas Java is tied to what your local timezone is.

The times are actually equivalent, since you're [two hours ahead of UTC](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cest).

If you want Clojure output to match Java, then you have to instruct the `SimpleDateFormat` instance to read the time in as UTC instead.

```
(def fmt
  (let [format (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "yyyy-MM-dd")]
    (.setTimeZone format (java.util.TimeZone/getTimeZone "UTC"))
    format))
```

Comment: So, if you do `(.format fmt d)`, it prints "2015-07-10". Just to summarize, SimpleDateFormat parses the string date using the user current time zone, unless configured differently, but when the date is converted to Clojure instant, it is converted to UTC time zone. But you still get the same string back if do `format` with the same formatter as in the example above.